# Is it possible to combine @After Advice with spring boot junit tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-aop

Is it somehow possibile to create @After Advice for each tests method in spring boot application? To write tests I am using groovy. Here example:

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner)
class MyTest {

  @Test
  void 'this is my test'() {
   ...
  }

}
```

My Advice class:

```
@Advice
public class MyAdvice() {

  @After("@annotation(org.junit.Junit)")
  public void after() {
     System.out.println("This is end of test case");
  }
}
```

Or event to log in @After annotation that failed (AssertException) or passed. When i tryied to run this code in my application I am getting something like "Method name 'this is my test' is invalid".

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for are [JUnit `@Rule`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20408020/1850609)?

Comment: It won't work with Spring AOP for the simple reason the unit test isn't a spring managed bean. Spring AOP only works for Spring managed beans.